# Installation via grub in disk

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install Linuxmint in Xubuntu by following steps:

1. Editing `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`,add following contents to the bottom of the file:

   ```
   menuentry “live mint” {
       insmod loopback
       loopback loop (hd0,6)/mint14.iso
       linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/mint14.iso
       initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
   }
   ```
2. `sudo update-grub`

when I execute this command, console didn’t show “Found linux Mint” message.
what’s wrong?

And anyone can use this method to install linux sucessfully?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regularly use the loopback method to boot Ubuntu, never tried Mint. 
ISO does have to be configured to work with loop back. Ubuntu desktop works, but server version does not. 
Is partition 6 on the boot drive the partition with mint14.iso? And ISO is at top level in that folder?
Does Mint store boot files in /casper folder like Ubuntu. Others like Knoppix use /boot/isolinux or gparted uses /live. Sometimes I have to review grub or syslinux menu entries in ISO to see actual path.

This will boot an ISO from a hard drive.
ISO Booting with Grub 2 from Hard drive

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Examples - you may copy & edit for your path & ISO version

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples